# Different behaviour observed when using SEH (structured exception handling)

Tags: c++, windows, exception, seh

I was doing some experiments with SEH. In my code I wrote the error causing block in __try clause and a handler in __except().

```
__try{
Test *pTest = 0;
int k = pTest->GetValue();
cout << "continue after exception" << endl;
}
__except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION,EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
 cout << "caught!!" << endl;
}
cout << "Exception handled" << endl;
```

The second parameter to __except() is either of these -

EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH   Exception is not recognized. Continue to search up the stack for a handler, first for containing try-except statements, then for handlers with the next highest precedence.

EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION   Exception is recognized but dismissed. Continue execution at the point where the exception occurred.

EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER   Exception is recognized. Transfer control to the exception handler by executing the __except compound statement, then continue execution at the point the exception occurred.

When I use EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION/EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER it does not continue execution at the point of exception occurrence (may be I am misinterpreting the meaning of point of exception occurrence). 
When I run it in debug mode, the output is

```
caught
Exception handled
```

When I run it in release mode, the output is

```
continue after exception
Exception handled
```

I could not understand why it is behaving differently. Anyone please help.

Comment: show content of the GetValue() method

Comment: Show us the definition of `Test` and show us how debug and release options differ with respect to SEH and C++ exceptions, there are options for that. Or better yet show us the disassembly of the `__try{}` block in the release mode. It may have some better clues.

Comment: I'm fearing that `pTest` is a pointer to a class and it may not need to be dereferenced in order to execute `GetValue()` and the compiler recognizes that when optimizations are enabled in the release mode. Or maybe even it sees `GetValue()` as useless and does not generate any code to call it. It's also possible that the compiler sees that dereferencing a NULL pointer results in undefined behavior and decides to punish your for it at compile time by screwing with your code, it has every right to do it. `gcc` is notorious for doing it.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. You are right. Because of compiler optimizations for null pointer check it was not actually raising the exception_access_violation. When I threw the exception explicitly using RaiseException() then it started showing similar behavior in both debug\release mode. But EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER is not doing exactly what documentation says. According to the documentation it should first execute the block {} after __except() & then continue execution at the point of exception occurrence.

Comment: You either misunderstood the documentation or did something wrong. SEH works fine. I'm moving the above comment into my answer since that's the actual debug vs release problem.

Comment: Yes as I said earlier I misinterpreted it.so could you please brief me about what EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER does

Comment: If the value of the expression in `__except()` is `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER` at exception time, the body in `{}` (right under `__except()`) will be executed and the rest of the body in `{}` right under `__try` will not. That's basically what you have written in the question and what the documentation says. There's no second parameter in `__except()`, there's one and only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Joachim points out correctly about the comma operator problem.

I think, the `__except()` should look like this:

```
__except((GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) ?
         EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER :
         EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
```

This will make the exception handler execute if the exception is an access violation. If it's not, the exception will propagate up to the closest outer `__try`, if any.

I'm fearing that `pTest` is a pointer to a class and it may not need to be dereferenced in order to execute `GetValue()` and the compiler recognizes that when optimizations are enabled in the release mode. Or maybe even it sees `GetValue()` as useless and does not generate any code to call it. It's also possible that the compiler sees that dereferencing a NULL pointer results in undefined behavior and decides to punish your for it at compile time by screwing with your code, it has every right to do it. gcc is notorious for doing it, for example.

Comment: I have edited the code as per your advice. But even the exception caught is EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION it is not displaying the string "caught!!" in Release mode

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION,EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER
```

doesn't do what you expect it to. What it does is compare the result of `GetExceptionCode()` with `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, but the result of the whole expression is `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER`.

Read more about the comma operator [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

What you want to do is, probably:

```
GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION || GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER
```

Comment: `GetExceptionCode()` does not return `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim for answering. But I am still clueless that why it behaves differently in debug/release mode.